# Android - unable to resolve java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, error-handling

I am having trouble find a solution or even finding the cause of this error. This error did not exist in the same code in Eclipse(used for testing), but when used in Android Studio app crashes with error.

From Logcat:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at com.bmc.thirdparty.org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle$MultiLineToStringStyle.<init>(ToStringStyle.java:2135)
            at com.bmc.thirdparty.org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle.<clinit>(ToStringStyle.java:79)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.Config.if(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.Config.applyDefaults(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.apitransport.ApiConfig.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.Config.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.Config.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.session.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.session.a.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.ARServerUser.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at flashmanagment.app.ARS.initializeServer(ARS.java:41)
            at flashmanagment.app.MainActivity.loadData(MainActivity.java:51)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; regionStart=0; regionLength=3
            at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:504)
            at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1333)
            at com.bmc.thirdparty.org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils.getJavaVersionAsFloat(SystemUtils.java:1122)
            at com.bmc.thirdparty.org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils.<clinit>(SystemUtils.java:818)
            at com.bmc.thirdparty.org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle$MultiLineToStringStyle.<init>(ToStringStyle.java:2135)
            at com.bmc.thirdparty.org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle.<clinit>(ToStringStyle.java:79)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.Config.if(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.Config.applyDefaults(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.apitransport.ApiConfig.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.Config.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.Config.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.session.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.session.a.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.ARServerUser.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at flashmanagment.app.ARS.initializeServer(ARS.java:41)
            at flashmanagment.app.MainActivity.loadData(MainActivity.java:51)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Is this an error with the library I imported from bmc?

Relevant code from main activity, called from button click:

```
   public void loadData(View v){
        ARS.getInstance().initializeServer("username","password");   
    }
```

And from Java Class:

```
public class ARS {

public static ARS instance = new ARS();

public static ARServerUser server;
public static ARS getInstance(){
    return instance;
}

public void initializeServer(String user, String password){
    server = new ARServerUser(user,password,null,"serverStringHere",portNumberHere);

}
```

Again, this same code was used with no error in Eclipse. Any helped would be be much appreciated.

EDIT for SystemUtils.java:1122

```
    1118    private static float More ...getJavaVersionAsFloat() {
1119        if (JAVA_VERSION_TRIMMED == null) {
1120            return 0f;
1121        }
1122        String str = JAVA_VERSION_TRIMMED.substring(0, 3);
1123        if (JAVA_VERSION_TRIMMED.length() >= 5) {
1124            str = str + JAVA_VERSION_TRIMMED.substring(4, 5);
1125        }
1126        try {
1127            return Float.parseFloat(str);
1128        } catch (Exception ex) {
1129            return 0;
1130        }
1131    }
```

Comment: What is SystemUtils.java line 1122?

Comment: @immibis added this in post

Answer (score 0):

You should give more information about your program, as this code isn't the full picture. you are trying to call button click but your application is not in the correct state.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is a problem with the library making some assumptions about the Java version format, which must differ between the two environments - Eclipse and Android Studio.

The variable/constant `JAVA_VERSION_TRIMMED` has been set to something with a length of 1, but the library is assuming it's longer.

To debug further, you should set a breakpoint in the static initializer block on SystemUtils line 818, or otherwise check what happens on that line.

Your choices, once that is shown, will vary. It may be the case that you cannot affect the library. While Apache Commons Lang is open source and would be possible to contribute to, you may find it harder to route these changes through the BMC libraries.